# How to save/load an ObservableCollection of custom class type in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have created a custom class, named `BrowserItem` that I am using in my application, that contains a lot of values. I am using this class in an ObservableCollection to store a collection of items. For some reason, although this implementation works while my application is running, I cannot properly get these values to persist when the application closes and then reopens. I am not sure how to properly save and then reload the ObservableCollection of type BrowserItem.

BrowserItem.cs

```
[DataContract]
public class BrowserItem

{
    [DataMember]
    public FullWebBrowser Browser
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Url
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public BitmapImage ImageUri
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Notification
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public bool DisplayNotification
    {
        get
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Notification);
        }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Message
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string GroupTag
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    //for translation purposes (bound to HubTile Title on MainPage) 
    public string TileName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Setting.cs (my class that saves and loads from IsolatedStorage)

```
public class Setting<T>
{
    string name;
    T value;
    T defaultValue;
    bool hasValue;

    public Setting(string name, T defaultValue)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            //Check for the cached value
            if (!this.hasValue)
            {
                //Try to get the value from Isolated Storage
                if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue(this.name, out this.value))
                {
                    //It hasn't been set yet
                    this.value = this.defaultValue;
                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[this.name] = this.value;
                }
                this.hasValue = true;
            }
            return this.value;
        }

        set
        {
            //Save the value to Isolated Storage
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[this.name] = value;
            this.value = value;
            this.hasValue = true;
        }
    }

    public T DefaultValue
    {
        get { return this.defaultValue; }
    }

    // Clear cached value
    public void ForceRefresh()
    {
        this.hasValue = false;
    }
}
```

Settings.cs (where the ObservableCollection is initialized)

```
public static Setting<ObservableCollection<BrowserItem>> BrowserList = new Setting<ObservableCollection<BrowserItem>>("Browsers", new ObservableCollection<BrowserItem>());
    public static Setting<string> InitialUri = new Setting<string>("InitialUri", "http://www.bing.com");
```

In the above class, InitialUri works fine when new values are saved and then used later, but I believe the issue with the ObservableCollection is its type being `BrowserItem`. I do not know how to make it so `BrowserItem` will be able to be used in the ObservableCollection to save and retrieve items that are added to the ObservableCollection. An example of adding an item is below

TabsPage.xaml.cs

```
void addNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapImage newTileImage = new BitmapImage();

        var newItem = new BrowserItem() { Browser = new FullWebBrowser(), Url = "http://www.bing.com", ImageUri = newTileImage, Title = "new", /*Notification = "",*/ Message = "new browser", GroupTag = "TileGroup", TileName = "new" };

        newItem.Browser.InitialUri = Settings.InitialUri.Value;
        Settings.BrowserList.Value.Add(newItem);
    }
```

Items in the ObservableCollection can be used while the application is active, but not once the application is activated once closed?

Answer (score 3):

I had same kind of requirement in my earlier project

Create a class to save and read data from the ObservableCollection

```
public class SerializeHelper
    {

        public static void SaveData<T>(string fileName, T dataToSave)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                try
                {

                    if (store.FileExists(fileName))
                    {
                        store.DeleteFile(fileName);
                    }

                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                        serializer.WriteObject(stream, dataToSave);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                    return;
                }

            }
        }

        public static T ReadData<T>(string fileName)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {

                if (store.FileExists(fileName))
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            return default(T);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return default(T);
            }
        }

    }
```

### Saving Data in ISO Store

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomClass> AllEvents = new public ObservableCollection<CustomClass>();

//AllEvents.Add(customclassref1);
//AllEvents.Add(customclassref2);
//AllEvents.Add(customclassref3);
SerializeHelper.SaveData<ObservableCollection<CustomClass>>("AllEvents", AllEvents);
```

### Retrieving Data from ISO store

```
AllEvents = (ObservableCollection<CustomClass>)SerializeHelper.ReadData<ObservableCollection<CustomClass>>("AllEvents");
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, when retrieving the `AllEvents` from ISO store, the collection is null?

Comment: @Matthew Check the item count of the all events before storing in the ISO Store..

Comment: @Matthew Check the Existence of file in the ISO Store using Debug